# How to Run as a TestNG test file

Tags: java, maven, testng

When I right-click the class file and choose "Run As" TestNG isn't an option.

I've added the TestNG jars by adding the dependency in the pom.xml and running as a Maven install. When I right-click my project and choose Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Library, TestNG doesn't show up in the list. This is an existing project and I see JUnit as well as a few others not pertaining to testing. Am I missing something to get this added? I'm able to import and use items from the TestNG API.

Comment: Assuming you are using Eclipse . You need to install https://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was running it to begin with, I only had a class with a @BeforeTest annotation and Eclipse wasn't seeing it as a Test Case. As soon as I added @Test to the next class for the first.

So the answer is to make sure there's a actual `@Test` test case class in the class file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install testng in eclipse

Can install by searching in Eclipse Marketplace or install as new software . For more details https://testng.org/doc/eclipse.html

Comment: I think this is correct. I don't have the plug-in installed; only the jar files through the Maven build.

Answer (score -1):

Please ensure if there are test cases under @Test annotations and check if that test annotation is imported from 'org.testng.annotations.Test' and not related to Junit.

Comment: This is pretty close the correct answer. When I was running it to begin with, I only had a class with a ```@BeforeTest``` annotation and Eclipse wasn't seeing it as a Test Case. As soon as  I added ```@Test``` to the next class for the first test case, It showed up.